# getting started: no module called bpy outside of Blender

Tags: python

After `sudo apt-get install blender` on Ubuntu 12.10, I have Blender version `2.63`

However, I can not import the relevant scripting Library

```python
Python 3.2.3 (default, Sep 25 2013, 19:36:10) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bpy
>>> import Blender
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Blender
```

Later on, I would like to use numPy and Blender to create some figures for 3D printing, as a friend has suggested.

Comment: It looks like your are trying to use blender as a python module, which is currently only supported as an experimental feature. See the [wiki for instructions](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule). Instead try executing scripts from inside blender. See the wiki on the [python console](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Console) and the text editor. Also see the [scripting page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the link to the [text editor wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Text_editor).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10972637/321973

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`bpy` is only available when a script is being run from the Python interpreter **in Blender**. You can't access it from an external interpreter. The `bpy` module itself is located in the Python environment supplied with Blender (if you download the zip-file, rather than the installer).

To use the `bpy` module, open the script in Blender's Script Editor.

Comment: Well, does exist a coomand line to launche blender script editor then "paste" or "run" any other script then export?. I mean without use GUI/X and of course, without the "experimental" blender as python module. Maybe the answer is " the experimental " but, i must ask. thx.

Comment: I realize this is old, but to for anyone else with the same question as @m3nda: You can run blender in a GUI-less mode and excecute your python script via:
`blender --background --python my_script.py -- my_argument1 my_argument` or similar.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, this can't be done straight forwardly.

But, there is an **experimental** feature you can try. Basically you build a Blender with some special CMAKE settings. Here is the complete "HowTo" *(from @Ideasman)*: [Blender as a Python Module](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule).

Also notice that Blender (currently) works with python 3.3.

Comment: That is interesting. I should try it out sometime.

Comment: really interesting ... exporting 3d models as scripts, so you can easily modify some parts before rendering/exporting.

Comment: the link is broken, is there any chance you can update?

Comment: Sorry, the page is gone (certainly with the rise of Blender 2.8). But you may find something interresting in there : https://pypi.org/project/bpy/ (I haven't tried it BTW).

Answer (score 4):

The `bpy` module is only accessible from the Python interpreter built-in to Blender. It is tightly integrated to Blender's runtime process, and is not primarily meant to be accessed like a library from a standalone Python process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fake-bpy-module](https://github.com/nutti/fake-bpy-module) instead.

From the description of the repo:

> fake-bpy-module is the collections of the fake Blender Python API modules for the code completion in commonly used IDEs.