# How to install Blender sub-process modules to run Blender in background?

Tags: python, command-line, documentation

Does anyone know how to install [BlenderAsPyModule](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3AIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) on a Linux machine?

As a beginner, I don't understand how to do it.

Is there a simplified guide?

Comment: I do not know how to install `BlenderAsPyModule`, but if your main goal is to run Blender in the background you can start it with the command-line option `-b`. You can even pass it a python script to do your rendering with the option `--python myScript.py`. Have a look at [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18809/blender-game-engine-via-python/18813#18813) and the [documentation of the command line options](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Command_Line) for more information.

Comment: Hi @maddin45, thanks for the reply , is it possible to import and export the models using this?? on background ?

Comment: If you just want to open a .blend file you can add it to the command line options: `blender myFile.blend -b --python myScript.py`. If you need to import a model using an importer script you can do it in the python script you passed to Blender. You will have to add the path where the importer script lies to your script's system path. For the .obj importer this would be: `import sys`, `sys.path.insert(0, '<blender_root+something>/scripts/addons/io_scene_obj')`. Then import the importer script `import import_obj` and call `import_obj.load(0, bpy.context, 'someFile.obj')`

Comment: Hi @maddin45 i can understand what you are saying, but can you provide any online document related to this ??

Comment: Not really, sorry. I do not know of any tutorials regarding background rendering using python. I had a similar problem some time ago and solved it by searching for pieces of code in google and reading through the [Python API documentation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/#blender-python-documentation).