# How to import bpy module in PyCharm IDE?

Tags: python, scripting

I know that [bpy is not available in python outside of blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/getting-started-no-module-called-bpy-outside-of-blender) which is totally fine, however I'd like to work on my blender python scripts using an IDE (in my case [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) from Jetbrains).

Therefore I'd like to somehow let the IDE know about the `bpy` module so my `import bpy` statements are not marked red and also autocompletion features would work. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have PyCharm on this machine, but have used it with Blender on my dev machine. So I can't detail the setup now - but for starters, see this dev doc regarding debugging Blender with Eclipse: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Tools/Debugging/Python_Eclipse

should be close enough for you to use with PyCharm (which is a custom eclipse). I presume you're okay with local (single machine) debugging - that's what I have setup in Eclipse/PyDev, tho in other Python work, I came across a browser-based setup that I adapted to PyDev - so now I debug Blender in the Browser - with the api docs in the 'tab next door' - very convenient.

if you're interested in remote debugging instead, see this recent dev blog entry: http://code.blender.org/2015/10/debugging-python-code-with-pycharm/

m23d